# Rails destroy method for subsclass models not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to build a rails site for games. I have created 2 models, Table and Player. To accomodate for different types of games for each table, I decided to subclass the Table and Player model. For example, I have a Blackjack class that extends Table model and BlackjackPlayer class that extends Player model.

To create my Table and Player models:
`rails g resource Table type:string data:text`
`rails g resource Table type:string data:text table_id:integer`
I included the column type to accommodate for the subclass. Player model has table_id because each table can have many players

After creating the base Table and Player class, I created a subclass for each. Lets use Blackjack for example. Here is my blackjack.rb file in models directory:

```
class Blackjack < Table
  has_many :blackjackPlayers, foreign_key: "table_id"
end
```

Here is my blackjack_player.rb file in models directory

```
class BlackjackPlayer < Player
  belongs_to :blackjack, foreign_key: "table_id"
end
```

I naively expected subclassing to be as simple as this, but I am wrong. Here is what I don't understand. In rails console, I create a few objects:

```
table = Blackjack.create
table.blackjackPlayers.create
table.blackjackPlayers.create
```

When I print out `table.blackjackPlayers.length`, I correctly get 2.

However, when I destroy a blackjackPlayer, the row destruction does not seem to propagate correctly:

`table.blackjackPlayers[0].destroy`

After the destroy, I still get 2 when I print out `table.blackjackPlayers.length` but I was expecting 1 instead. The row is correctly removed from the Player table.

Why is this happening and how can I get subclassing to work the way its supposed to? I'm using rails 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use destroy then you use

```
table.blackjackPlayers.length
```

It does not look in the database again for a refresh.

You need to look at the database again for the updated count. Try:

```
table.reload
table.blackjackPlayers.length
```

or

```
BlackJack.count
BlackjackPlayer.count
```

And see the real count.

Comment: table.reload is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did some more testing/digging and found out the problem. When you retrieve an object from the database, it lives in the memory. When you delete an item from the database, the object from the memory does not change and thus the length will not change. You would need to retrieve the object from the database again in order to have the updated records.